# IN SQL condition in Sugar ORM

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'd like to execute SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM arr1 WHERE name IN ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
```

in SugarORM, but I've no idea how use IN statement in this library. Documentation is really modest. I don't want to use OR beacuse args list may be long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic find method. Assuming Arr1 is the name of your object model:

```
Arr1.find(Arr1.class," name IN(?,?,?) ",param1, param2, param3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
    public static List<Product> findByIdList(List<String> idList) {
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer("id IN (");

    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
        queryString.append("?").append(i == idList.size() - 1 ? ")" : ",");
    }

    List<Product> products = Product.find(Product.class, queryString.toString(), idList.toArray(new String[idList.size()]));
    return products;
}
```